PBI - SVG circle isn't displaying
I'm trying to replicate a visual that I found at the link below; however, the circle isn't displaying. I've tried adjusting the parameters, but I still haven't found a workaround to make it function.
Link to the article:
https://datameerkat.com/templates/Circle-progress-chart
Sample File:
https://github.com/tomecsek21/pbix_file/blob/main/svg_circle_test.pbix
Could anyone please advise? Thanks

I did a diff on your code and the sample code and there is no material difference. I suspect the sample code is missing something in the circle logic and I have always found using transform, rotate and translate far from intuitive. If you want an easier circle implementation, try the one from my sample file here.
https://github.com/PBI-David/SVG
Something strange is happening with the file you sent. However, if you create a brand new .pbix and drop in the following code into a HTML Lite visual, it works fine.
SVG Donut = 
VAR per = 0.25
VAR height = 140
VAR width = 150
VAR radius = (height/2) - 2.5
VAR circ = 2*PI()* radius
VAR val = FORMAT( per, "#%;-#%;0%")
VAR a1 =  IF( per >= 0,(per *circ),0)
VAR a2 = (1-per) *circ  
VAR offset = 0.25*circ
VAR sort  = IF(per <0, 1000+ABS(per),  10000+ per)
RETURN
 
"<svg  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 " & width & " " & height & "'   >
 /*" & sort & "*/ 
<rect width='150' height='150' style='fill:rgba(0,0,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:'/>
<circle class='background' cx='" & radius + 8 & "' cy='50%' r='" & radius & "' fill='transparent' stroke='#dde1e3' stroke-width='5'   />
<circle class='segment' cx='" & radius + 8 & "' cy='50%' r='" & radius & "' fill='transparent' stroke='#2c76b4' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='" & a1 & " " & a2 & "' stroke-dashoffset='" & offset & "'></circle>
<style>
    .percent {
          font: bold 12pt Arial;
    }
  </style>
<text  x='" & width/2 & "' y='50%' class='percent' text-anchor='middle' fill='#666666' alignment-baseline='middle'  >" & val &"</text>
</svg>"



It worked perfectly except for one minor issue - the circle starts at position '3AM' on the clock instead of '12AM', which I would like to see. I played around with the rotation, but somehow I couldn't fix it. Interestingly, if I do it in your original file, it is displayed correctly, but not in mine. I also updated the file on GitHub so you can see..thanks!

I'll update now

even when I create a new .pbix the behavior is the same...but like I said when I do it in your file that you linked it is working as expected...I dont get it...thanks for looking into it!

I modified this section as follows and I get the right result on my end :

rotated the circle by -90 deg

Interesting. I wonder why one file works and the other does not? I have never seen this before and it doesn't make sense to me.

just FYI, I did a test on my colleague's NB, and it is behaving in the same way as I described... It doesn't make sense to me either, but at least it's been resolved by rotating the circle...
